# Dual monitor display problem

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, wayland, displayport

I have two identical monitors, but only one is recognized correctly, the other one fails to show the correct screen resolution.

The cold facts:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04 (community theme on wayland)
- PC: HP 8200 Ultra Slim (yes, yes I know, not the newest one around ;-))
- Monitors: 2 x Samsung S24C450 (24" screens)

These are the monitor stats:

- Monitor 1 connected via VGA works fine with screen resolution 1920 x 1200.  The monitor is recognized by Ubuntu as `Samsung Electric Company 24"`.
- Monitor 2 connected via VGA to DisplayPort with max screen resolution 1680 x 1050. The monitor is recognized by Ubuntu as `Integrated Tech Express Inc 27"`.

The first thing I did was checking the cables and switched the monitors. The problem continued for the monitor that is connected via DisplayPort.

I have googled around, but not really with any luck. I have looked for BIOS versions, and DisplayPort versions (1.1a), but no results that made any sense or could help in trouble shooting.

I changed between the different Ubuntu themes on the login screen, but were not able to change the screen resolution to a higher one than 1680 x 1050.

I have looked in terminal with `xrandr` and got the following result:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3600 x 1200, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 1680x1050+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   1680x1050     59.85*+
XWAYLAND1 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 520mm x 320mm
   1920x1200     59.88*+
```

I can see that the terminal results show the same resolution as what I can set in the GUI, but that's it.

**What can I do?**
**Does anyone have some ideas?**

Comment: If you can avoid connecting via VGA, it would be best to do so. It also looks like you're running under wayland. Have you logged out and tried the non-wayland session instead?

Comment: Hi. One of the first things I did was logging out at trying a non-wayland session. That was the same result with the minor change to the second monitor displayed as  "Integrated Tech Express Inc 23" instead of "Integrated Tech Express Inc 27".

I only have VGA and DisplayPort as connection possibilities on the motherboard, so it is a bit difficult do avoid VGA connection.

/niller

Comment: OK. VGA requires manual configuration as it does not provide EDID from the monitor to tell the system what video is supported. I'm surprised you didn't get just 1024x768 or such on it.